# parse xml using xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

I have an xml file as shown below. I want to use xmllint to parse it such that if the category is "SciFi", it will display the "isbn" number.

After struggling a bit I could figure out how to print *only* the **category** or *only* the **isbn** number ; but cannot figure out how to add the condition.

```
<book>
 <name>
  <category>SciFi</category>
  <isbn>12345678</isbn>
 </name>
 <name>
  <category>Mystery</category>
  <isbn>23456789</isbn>
 </name>
<book>
```

Edit : The version of xmllint I have does **not** support xpath

I made a mistake in my original post ; corrected xml above

xmllint --version produces

```
xmllint: using libxml version 20626
```

I use the following commands to print the information

```
cat /book/name[1]/category
cat /book/name[2]/category

cat /book/name[1]/isbn
cat /book/name[2]/isbn
```

Comment: Why not switch to a newer version (or even another program) that does support xpath?

Comment: And how do I justify that to the support team to get it installed on some 1000+ Linux servers ?

Comment: What version of xmllint are you using and how are you printing only the `category` or `isbn`?

Comment: I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a poor tool for the purpose.  If you have xmllint installed, do you have xsltproc?  That would be more useful, I think.

Also, just to be sure, have you tried 
`cat /book/name[category='SciFi']/isbn`
?